# How to install mysqlnd for php 5.3.3 on Centos 6.2

Tags: mysql, php, centos, yum, lamp

I have just down graded my PHP-installation from 5.3.9 to 5.3.3. This in order to be able to use yum/EPEL instead of compiling everything myself.

Appearently, mysqlnd-support isn't available in 5.3.3 and since I don't want to compile the source myself anymore, I cannot just add it during that phase.

I would like to use yum/EPEL, but there seems to be no package for mysqlnd available yet.

Any suggestions for how to do this (other than re-programming the application)?

Comment: The `mysqlnd` driver is built in to 5.3 as standard?

Comment: Nope (at least not for me...), but you have the links where you can get it from here: http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en (this works with 5.3.3). @cjc has some suggestions as well, the answer is updated after I solved my problem so I haven't tried that actual solution. Please note that if you use my link that repository is not searched by default when you do some yum-activity, don't remember how to include it but it's on their page somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is in Atomicorp's RPM repostiroy:

http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/6/i386/RPMS/

You will probably need to do a package upgrade to 5.3.9 using their reposistory.  Take a look at http://www.atomicorp.com/downloads.html for the shell script that will install and activate that repository.

Comment: Thanks again cjc, this was some related problem to the change to EPEL that you helped out with. It worked fine using the repo and yum.